# Erasing existing text files from the system.DocumentsDirectory in Corona with new apk installation

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My application reads and writes score data in the text file in system.DocumentsDirectory.

When I install application apk again, I receive message during the installation "All previous user data will be saved" ,and in the application I see the score data from the previous installed application version.

I don't want to save previous data ( I want score = 0 ) with the new installation. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a version number into the text file. Compare the version numbers on start and clear the
data if they are different. You could also include a reset button to let the user clear the data.